# Add a close button to a rich:tooltip

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is there an easy way for adding a "close button" to a rich:toolTip (so that it will remain visible until one clicks such button)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

richfaces provides a further component called rich:popupPanel to achieve this.

```
<h:panelGrid onmouseover="#{rich:component('popup')}.show()">
    <h:outputText value="Open popup" />
</h:panelGrid>
<rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
<f:facet name="controls">
    <h:outputLink value="#"
        onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;">X</h:outputLink>
</f:facet>
...
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

use tag `hideEvent="none"`

```
<rich:toolTip name="tooltipTest" id="tooltipTest" hideEvent="none">
    <a4j:commandButton value="Close" onclick="#{rich:component('tooltipTest')}.hide(); return false;" />
</rich:toolTip>
```